# Delete all files from a second level directoty inside a hidden directoty in Ubuntu MATE 21.04 using a Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have gone through quite a few threads on AskUbuntu and elsewhere but as it sounds, all of them are about deleting hidden files, while I'm trying to:

**delete non-hidden files, from a non-hidden directory, which is inside a hidden directory**.

I like to delete all files inside `/home/admn/.cache/thumbnails/normal/` directory using a Bash script.

The simple script that I have created:

`sudo nano /usr/local/scripts/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob

rm '/home/admn/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*'

shopt -u dotglob
```

Note: As suggested, I've tried using double-quotes `"` in the script, but still getting the same error.

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/scripts/test.sh`

The error I'm getting:

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/admn/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*': No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like single-quotes (`'`) vs double-quotes (`"`) confusion (...or no quotes at all). A common question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash for a great explanation.

Comment: @user535733 just edited the script, and tried with double-quotes `"`, still getting the same error. Thanks.

Comment: @user535733 I did glance over the link. The accepted answer there says: `Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will. For example: variables, backticks, certain \ escapes, etc.` I don't know what did I miss there.

Comment: Keep reading. It's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither single nor double quotes will allow expansion of the `*` glob - that needs to be outside the quotes i.e.

```
rm '/home/admn/.cache/thumbnails/normal/'*
```

or

```
rm "/home/admn/.cache/thumbnails/normal/"*
```

However, since your string doesn't contain any shell-special characters, you could omit the quotes altogether

```
rm /home/admn/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*
```

Comment: Also do I need to use `shopt -s dotglob | shopt -u dotglob` ? 'Coz as per: `https://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html` it's for hidden files, while I'm trying to delete non-hidden files. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jags no you don't need `shopt -s dotglob` - sorry I missed that. In fact you might want `shopt -u dotglob` to be certain that the expansion of `*` does **not** include hidden files

Comment: Then `shopt -u dotglob` must go at the beginning of the script, right? Thanks alot.

Comment: ... @Jags so long as it goes before you try to use the `*` glob you're good I think